# Geolocation.getCurrentPosition: Timeout expired

Tags: geolocation, ionic2

I am using Ionic2.

I am using the following code, but get an error:

```
import { Geolocation } from 'ionic-native';

    public getPosition(): void {
        if (this.markers && this.markers.length > 0) {
            var marker: google.maps.Marker = this.markers[0]; // only one
            this.latitude = marker.getPosition().lat();
            this.longitude = marker.getPosition().lng();
            this.getJobRangeSearch(this.searchQuery);
        } else {
            let options = {
                timeout: 10000,
                enableHighAccuracy: true
            };
            Geolocation.getCurrentPosition(options).then((position) => {
                this.latitude = position.coords.latitude;
                this.longitude = position.coords.longitude;
                this.getJobRangeSearch(this.searchQuery);
            }).catch((error) => {
                console.log(error);
                this.doAlert(error+' Timeout trying to get your devices Location');
            });
        }
    }
```

**error:**

> PositionError {message: "Timeout expired", code: 3, PERMISSION_DENIED:
>   1, POSITION_UNAVAILABLE: 2, TIMEOUT: 3}

**package.json**

```
"ionic-native": "^1.3.2",
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Looking [here](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/native/geolocation/) shows I needed to  do the following:

```
$ ionic plugin add cordova-plugin-geolocation
```